# Unexpected behaviour with @Valid annotation in Java method in a Spring Hibernate application

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have following doubt with following code, I have written:

```
public Optional<A> getA(@Valid @NotBlank  String aId) {
        ..
        return a;
 }
```

Problem is, when I am calling this function with blank `aId` as `getA("")`, the function body is getting executed, where it should not have. I know there is a way to do the same as following:

```
Validate.notBlank(aId);
```

But I would like to achieve the same with annotation as above. May be, something I am missing here.

Comment: Looks like your `getA()` is just a regular method which won't be intercepted by Spring to do the annotation processing. You would either have to do something complex to make Spring intercept the method call, or do manual validation which is simpler.

Comment: Did you annotated your class with @Validated?

Comment: @Shubham even after adding this, it does not work.